# Parsing JSON that contains other language characters in UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: java, json, eclipse, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the below JSON which contains a special character:

```json
{
  "Laptopà":"Dell"
}
```

When I try to parse this in **Eclipse IDE** with **UTF-8** Character Encoding, I'm getting a **JSONException** stating **JSONObject not found**. Below is the code snippet I've used for parsing,

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
jsonObj.getString("Laptopà");
```

Which gives the below exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Laptop(Junk Character instead of à)"] not found
```

I have been searching for a while and found no clue. Looking forward for your help on solving this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack trace. Please also tell us which JSON library you are using.

Comment: I have used json jar with version 20171018  and the exception trace does not have much,This is the Exception org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Laptop(Junk Character instead of à)"] not found.Some junk character is showing instead of agrave character.

Comment: @karthikeyan That is important information which needs to be part of your question.  Any time you ask a Java question that involves an exception, always include the full stack trace of the exception in your question.

Comment: Is `json` a String?  Did you read it from some outside source, or did you actually write that literal JSON content in your source code?  How do you know you’re parsing it as UTF-8?  I see nothing in the code you’ve supplied that specifies UTF-8.

Comment: As VGR remarked, the code that actually _acquires_ the JSON as string is not shown. Please add it. Note that according to specs, JSON _files_ should _always_ be encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: All signs are pointing to your String not containing the same characters as the file. Please show your code for reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you read `JSON` payload from `File` you need to use `JSONTokener`. In case you have `JSON` as `String` in your `Java` class check whether file is stored with `UTF-8` encoding. Example code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class OrgJsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String key = "Laptopà";

        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        // Read from file
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new FileReader(jsonFile)));
        System.out.println(jsonObject.getString(key));

        // Read from `JSON` string
        System.out.println(new JSONObject("{\"Laptopà\":\"Dell\"}").getString(key));
    }
}
```

Above code prints properly `Dell` two times.